# Database Cleaner strategy is cleaning the table mention in except block of truncation strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, database-cleaner

I have the following database cleaner strategy

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[roles, users, other_tables]}
```

It's still cleaning the roles table and I don't have any dependent destroy on the models that role belongs to.
This does not look like intended behavior.
Other than Role table, data is persistent across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first make sure to define the array correctly, please check in the console what it evaluates to:

```
> %w[roles, users, other_table]
=> ["roles,", "users,", "other_table"]
```

There's (probably) no table called `roles,` (with a comma at the end).

Correct that to:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[roles users other_tables]}
```

because:

```
> %w[roles users other_table]
=> ["roles", "users", "other_table"]
```